# How can I count the number of words in a file whilst editing the file in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I know I can use `wc` for counting characters, words and lines of files *at the command line*.

Is there any way I can can count the number of words *while in vim*?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can count words and lines inside `vi` using `vi`'s own counter:

Press <kbd>g</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>. Then the bottom line look for example like this:

```
Col 1 of 11; Line 1 of 106; Word 1 of 344; Byte 1 of 2644
```

Or use `vi`'s method to call shell commands:

```
:w !wc -w
```

This calls the save (`:w`) command first and then `wc -w` and shows the output. Example:

```
:w !wc -w
344

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go back to `vi`.

Comment: It is actually incorrect description of ``:w !<cmd>`` construct. It writes the current buffer to a pipe connected to the command. No separate write of the current buffer to a file is promised. Nevertheless, it does what question asked for.

Answer (score 6):

## Since `vim` version 7.4.1042

Since `vim` version 7.4.1042, one can simply alter the `statusline` as follows:

```
set statusline+=%{wordcount().words}\ words
set laststatus=2    " enables the statusline.
```

## Word count in `vim-airline`

Word count is provided standard by [`vim-airline`](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline#vim-airline---) for a number of file types, being at the time of writing:
[`asciidoc, help, mail, markdown, org, rst, tex ,text`](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/master/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim#L90)

If word count is not shown in the `vim-airline`, more often this is due to an unrecognised file type. For example, [at least for now](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/pull/2075), the compound file type [`markdown.pandoc`](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax#standalone) is not being recognised by `vim-airline` for word count. This can easily be remedied by amending the `.vimrc` as follows:

```
let g:airline#extensions#wordcount#filetypes = '\vasciidoc|help|mail|markdown|markdown.pandoc|org|rst|tex|text'
set laststatus=2    " enables vim-airline.
```

The `\v` statement overrides the default `g:airline#extensions#wordcount#filetypes` variable. The last line ensures `vim-airline` is enabled.

In case of doubt, the `&filetype` of an opened file is returned upon issuing the following command:

```
:echo &filetype
```

Here is a meta-example:

[image: vim-airline word count]

Answer (score 1):

You can also try for `:!wc  %` in Vim, though it counts the size of the file on-disk, not what is in Vim's buffer. This may or may not be what you wanted.

Comment: This counts what’s on disk (if anything), not what’s in the buffer — so if you have changed the contents of the buffer since the last save, or not saved at all, you’ll get the wrong count (or even an error if you’re creating a file).

Comment: Contra Stephen, this *is* a correct solution to "How can I count the number of words **in a file** whilst editing the file in vim", while the accepted answer strictly-speaking isn't (although it's ambiguous what was meant or whether it matters).

Comment: Funny that it's similar (minus the `-w` flag to restrict the output to words only) to a delete answer from 2014 by D_Bye (who apparently self-deleted it).

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to count number of words in a given piece of text (not whole file), use `\S\+` regexp.

1. Select the text of interest (visual mode)
2. `:s/\S\+//gn`

Result. Vim will show you something like this: `10 matches on 1 line`

When you hit `:` in visual mode, vim prepends your command with `'<,'>` which means to apply the command against the selected text.

`\S\+` captures words, that is groups of characters separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins such as [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) can provide word counts for a file (and selections) as part of a status bar.

Comment: This answer isn't link-only. I didn't include the specifics of any particular plugin, because (as you say) particular plugins might become outdated.

Comment: I stand corrected. However I would say in the future you should try to include relevant steps to implement the solution you are presenting. Thank you!