# How can I get the count of specific characters using vim in a file

Tags: vim

My question is similar to this one: [How can I count the number of words in a file whilst editing the file in vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145289/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-file-whilst-editing-the-file-in-vim)

But with a different task where I have to count characters with the search function in vim and write them at the of the file.

For example, if I have to count how many numeric characters are there, I would need something like this: `:%s/[0-9]/{g}` and after that a command that counts how many characters I have selected with that search.

Edit:

I'm trying a method where I first select all the characters that I want to count with `/[0-9]` and trying to use `'<,'>` like this: `'<,'> !wc -m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answer is ok, what I wanted is simply the count of the characters written out.

This can be achieved by pipelining `grep` and `wc`:

```
:%!grep -o '[0-9]' | wc -l
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer... I think you have to wait a couple of days :)

Comment: If you don't want to replace the contents of the editing buffer with the output of `wc`, use `:!grep -o '[0-9]' % | wc -l` instead.  (`%` is replaced by the current buffer's filename).

Comment: And if I want to append it to the end of the file: `:% !grep -o '[0-9]' | wc -l >> *file*` where `*file*` is the file I want to append to?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can try this:

```
111
222
333
~
~ 
:redi>>%|%s/\d//gn|redi END
9 matches in 3 lines
```

After that, update the buffer with

```
:e
```

Comment: And `\d` is what I want to look for, right?

Comment: @GeTo Yes, I'm used to the `[0-9]` pattern, but `\d` suits better.

Comment: I see, it was not updating the display then. But how can I display only the integer of the matches?